# How can I export my c# code logic (if-else-loops) in to text files (e.g XML) and later import it back and run?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, scripting

I have these requirements coming from client every week for some new logic or verification. For which I have to code new logic **(basically some if-else and loops)** and launch a **new build** for him. I want to avoid it by simply coding my logic in visual studio then writing a utility to export it to **XML** or something and send it to client via **e-mail**. He just have to place this file in some appropriate folder and the application will behave considering this logic.
Please suggest some solutions. My platform is **C# Asp.Net**.
Thanks

Comment: Deploy the code to a DLL and have the client put that in the application's folder?  What's so bad about having to *compile* your code?  (Especially when compared to the *vast assortment* of problems you're going to encounter from this proposed hack.)

Comment: Your problem is that a new build feels like a problem. You should be able to build and deploy in less than 20 minutes at the push of a button (or maybe a few buttons).

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do is as much of a death sentence as others are suggesting, there's lots of software out there that supports custom workflows. But that said, this is way too broad for us to be able to answer here, and I do share their concern about this particular use-case. If you wanted to go down that route, you'd better be very sure you're ready to support it, and it probably won't save you effort for just one client.

Answer (score 0):

Using .NET 4.6 and the NuGetPackage [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting/) you could implement a scripting engine to run your c# code residing in a textfile without building an assembly.

**Install NuGet Package:**

> Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.CSharp

**Implement TestClass with some basic C#-Code-Content:**

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestScript();
        }

        private static async void TestScript()
        {
            // Code snippet: a class with one string-property.
            string codeContent = @" using System;

                                    public class ScriptedClass
                                    {
                                        public string HelloWorld { get; set; }

                                        public ScriptedClass()
                                        {
                                            HelloWorld = ""Hello Roslyn!"";
                                        }
                                    }

                                    new ScriptedClass().HelloWorld";

            // Instanciate CSharpScriptEngine
            var engine = new CSharpScriptEngine();
            // Execute code and return string property (HelloWorld)
            var scriptingState = await engine.ExecuteAsync(codeContent);

            // Print return value from CSharpScript
            Console.WriteLine("Returned from CSharpScript: {0}", scriptingState.ReturnValue);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

**Implement a ScriptingEngine:**

```
            internal sealed class CSharpScriptEngine
            {
                public async Task<ScriptState<object>> ExecuteAsync(string codeContent)
                {
                    // Add references from calling assembly
                    ScriptOptions options = ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

                    // Run codeContent with given options
                    return await CSharpScript.RunAsync(codeContent, options);
                }
            }
```

**Read ScriptCode from textfile:**

So basically you could read some csharpcode from a textfile of your choice and run them on the fly:

```
        private static async void TestScript()
        {
            // Read in script file
            string codeContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\CSharpScriptTest.cs");

            var engine = new CSharpScriptEngine();
            // Run script
            var scriptingState = await engine.ExecuteAsync(codeContent);

            Console.WriteLine("Returned from CSharpScript: {0}", scriptingState.ReturnValue);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

In case you are wondering how all of this works under the hood, Roslyn will create a so called submission from your script code. A submission is an in memory assembly containing the types generated around your script code, which can be identified among the assemblies in the current AppDomain by a ℛ prefix in the name.

The precise implementation details are not important here (though, for example, scriptcs heavily relies on understanding in detail how Roslyn works to provide its extra features), but it's important to know that submissions can be chained together. When they are chained, variables, methods or classes defined in an earlier submission are available to use in subsequent submissions, creating a feature of a C# [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) (read-evaluate-print loop).

[C# and Visual Basic - Use Roslyn to Write a Live Code Analyzer for Your API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx)

Hope it helps